# Header jumbled when initially loading

Tags: css, wordpress, header, load

As forewarning, I am a bit of a novice at these things. My website http://articlemerchant.com/ initially loads with the header jumbled, then goes into place once the website is fully loaded. This doesn't affect the functionality of the site, but is distracting and looks unprofessional. Anyone know why the header is loading jumbled initially and how to fix it? I believe it has something to do with me editing the initial Wordpress theme's Child Theme, which loads later.

Answer (score 0):

I've checked and saw that you've got quite a bunch of CSS errors going on, that can make your site take more time to load, as the browser tries to understand those CSS lines even though there are small errors.

Have you validated the HTML and CSS? I strongly suggest that you do.

Anyway, I have found that plusone.js is giving you some problems to the loading time too, try removing it and reloading to see if the problem persists.